# How to replace Operations links (dropdown) by icons?

Tags: views, 8

I'd like to have something like that (icons as buttons)[image]   instead of text links in dropdown   [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but you could use CSS to hide the text and display an image background over the space instead.

Comment: Sometimes instead of adding contextual links I will add a global markup field and add my own markup to do this. But yes, the CSS approach is good imo.